# How can I give CREATE USER and GRANT privileges to an user in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I created a new user called `Hamza` in `localhost` then I tried to give it these 2 privileges:

- CREATE USER
- GRANT

For the creation everything is OK, but when it comes to granting the privileges I tried this query :

```
GRANT CREATE USER TO 'Hamza'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

And I got this error :

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TO 'Hamza'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION' at line 1
```

Could someone tell me how can I correct this syntax error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `ON object_name` here in your `GRANT` statement like

```
GRANT CREATE USER ON *.* TO 'Hamza'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```